# Is underlining the reputation of a just-do-it-for-me asker inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, comments

Recently I commented a just-do-it-for-me question by an old user with something like "More than 7000 (!) reputation points without trying to do something by yourself and adding an MWE?"

Now the comment is deleted: why?

If comments like this are not allowed, let us establish once and for all that just-do-it-for-me questions are perfectly acceptable, even if asked by an old user with high reputation.

Comment: The request was not "just do it", but for a ***premade*** solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comment was flagged as offensive and to be deleted. As that comment with the (non-) question was not on the topic but kind of caustically lecturing the OP, it was agreed to delete.

Replacing a "Why (!) didn't you do X ...?" by something like "It would be great if you would do X" would be more positive. Or "Please do X". Straightforward. No indirect question for a reason why not.

Comment: 1) I think we are exaggerating with the political correctness 2) it would have been fair to tell _me_ that my comment was deleted for that reason, so that I wouldn't rewrite the same text in other occasions (I did many time in the past).

Comment: I think CarLaTeX's second point is very important. I have sort of accepted that my comments can get moved to chat to avoid long tails of discussion hanging below posts or that they can get cleaned up without me realising it because they are seen as 'no longer needed'. I don't particularly like that, but it's how this site is supposed to work and I have to accept that. If on the other hand one of my comments gets removed because it is offensive, I would like to know about that. Sure, some people might start an argument and that is avoided if you don't tell them about the deletion, ...

Comment: ... but I for one would at least try to reconsider my behaviour, if i knew that my contents was removed because it was flagged as offensive and that flag was approved by a moderator. If I don't even get to know that my behaviour was out of line, chances are higher that I will go on behaving like this.

Comment: @moewe Exactly!

Comment: @CarLaTeX We are usually ok with many things. But once users flag for moderator attention, we have to decide for one or the other, even if we would let things go without the flag. There's a feedback comment field that goes only to the flagging user. It seems SE did not consider having a message field for the owner of a deleted comment. The moderators had to decide on 6,604 comment flags last year. So it's hard to discuss every single one or leave *additional* explaining comments. I guess one can see flags in the own profile? So one can see the reason? If not, it could be suggested as feature.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Regarding exaggerating political correctness: feel free to tell it publicly and visibly so we don't get thousands of flags but a bit fewer. Also, flagging is encouraged because users get shiny badges for it. I would prefer that users flag only because of content without any extra motivating sherriff badge.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I can't find a place where to see flagged comments in my profile, I'll ask on StackExchange Meta.

Comment: Apparently, the idea of automatic notification for own flagged comment is not something SX is keen on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323060.

Answer (score 2):

The comment was removed because I felt it was offensive. So, I flagged it as such. Sorry.

I haven't been around for quite some time, and I guess I have forgotten the rules.
A simple request to edit the question, or a reminder of the rules, would have been more
effective I believe.

Comment: My comment was caustic but I didn't think it was offensive because I didn't refer to your gender, ethnicity, religion, political party, you name it, but
only to your reputation on this site. I have used no bad words either. As I wrote in my comment to Stefan's answer, I used the same text many times in the past, but, since the moderators agree with you, I won't use it anymore in the future. However, I think it didn't clearly appear from your question that you were simply searching for a symbol since it was tagged `arrows` and `tikz-arrows`, I presumed you wanted to use them in a picture.